# How to resize twemoji emojis?

Tags: javascript, twemoji

I'm using [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) to style emojis on a page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  document.body = twemoji.parse(document.body)
 });
```

It works fine, however the default emojis turn out to be `72x72`:

```
<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/72x72/1f600.png">
```

I'd like twemoji to render `16x16` png or svg icons instead.

The docs does not explicitly say how to change the icon size, so I tried things like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  document.body = twemoji.parse(document.body, 
   {size: 16}
    )
 });
```

But none worked. How can I fix this?

Comment: dont they have 16x16 png files instead of 72x72?

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/tree/gh-pages/16x16

Comment: They have it but the problem is how to choose `16x16` instead of the default `72x72`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default size before running the parse() method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  // Set the size of the rendered Emojis
  // This can be set to 16x16, 36x36, or 72x72
  twemoji.size = '36x36';

  document.body = twemoji.parse(document.body);
});
```

Credit to [this page](https://codepen.io/nicknish/full/jWzMZG) for the tip (and to [this simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=twemoji+set+size) for finding it!).

Comment: This does work only for `twemoji.size = '72x72';` According to the docs: `the default PNG icon size is 72 pixels and there are no other PNG assets for 16 or 32.`

Comment: it's odd because they are there in the github repo. Perhaps there is an issue on the CDN

Comment: Right, I've just realized that I was using `v2` of the twemoji CDN. Using `<script src="//twemoji.maxcdn.com/twemoji.min.js"></script>` solved the problem. Thanks.